# Simple voltage inverter with mosfet/bjt

Tags: mosfet, bjt, inverter

I want to build a simple voltage inverter, just using two diodes and two caps to get a source of negative voltage.

[image]

The problem is, that my micro is running at 3.3V and I need at least -6V and about 10-15mA. I have a +8V rail availible in my circuit, so I need a way to use the 3.3V to switch the +8V. I tried simulating this in LTspice:
[image]
But it did not work very well, and it has the problem that when the mosfet is open, it is just wasting power on R41. How to do this correctly? I think I need more than one mosfet/bjt...

Comment: Nice diagrams how accurate does the -6V have to be?

Comment: Not very much, it can have quite a ripple, even dip down to -5V.

Comment: Btw, just wondering, should I just use a 555 timer powered directly from the 8V?

Comment: Consider replacing the 100R (R41) with an inductor. You may need a flyback diode across it if you draw no current from -Vout.

Comment: Erhmm... Why are you trying to build one when you don't understand how they work or have adequate specs?   -1V drop / 15mA implies switches must be < 60 Ohms so any CMOS inverter will work. BAT54 Vf=0.8 @ 200mApk.

Comment: It would be much easier to just use a 555 powered at +8V to drive your diode/charge pump. If you really wanted to use your MCU, you could do it in 3 transistors: an NPN to level shift 3.3V to +8V, followed by a complementary PNP+NPN in a totem pole as a class B amp to drive your diode/capacitor. Let know if still interested and I can draw it up, else go with 555 or a specially suited charge pump IC.

Comment: @Dan  You should start by representing the real impedance of each part including the load, source, cap and diodes using the Zc(f) for f= 0.35/Slew rate and slew rate = dV/dt=Ic/C=Vcc/ESR*C  then decide what efficiency you want for this "simple" cct. and then computer the driver ESR or Ic at driver to achieve Rload=330Ohm or 15mA @ 5.5V or whatever.  Then Dan will realize this driver needs to be Rload/1000 for< 1% loss using a 555 driver.

Answer (score 1):

You only have 3 active switches ( 1 FET 2 diodes and a 100R resistor ) instead of 4.

[image]
This is the ideal circuit. and ESR of switch and caps is key to your requirement with Load regulation error being 1V/@15mA = 67 Ohm  The ESR of 3.3V 74ALSxxx drivers are 22~33 Ohm for example.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of building it by yourself, but it's a generally wrong thing to do, unless you are a student. In any commercial development it would be cheaper, more reliable, more universal to use a charge pump IC. It would do same work, but generally better than you can. The number of components will be lower, you will not have to deal with EMI stuff (or at least it will be much simpler than if you layout a charge pump of your own). The assembly will cost less. I think you get the point...